# Send email to user once their account is locked using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Using the `devise` gem for Rails, is there a way to send an email to a user whenever their account has been locked? I haven't seen any examples of callbacks triggered by Devise just yet, but it's possible that I'm overthinking it.

The only thing that I can imagine is finding user accounts that have a recent `updated_at` attribute and determining storing whether or not a lockout email was sent, but this seems to be inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can sand email once the failed_attempts are > of Devise.maximum_attempts in your login method, then override `Devise`'s `active_for_authentication` method, so when an account is locked simply check if it is active for authentication so that email is not sent every time your user try to login, like this:

```
if active_for_authentication?
  if user.failed_attempts >= Devise.maximum_attempts
    user.lock_access!(send_instructions: true)
  else
    user.increment_failed_attempts
  end
end

def active_for_authentication?
  super && your_condition_is_valid?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old question, but I came across it today and thought I would share a couple of solutions.

### Solution 1

Devise has a built-in workflow for this. You can open up your Devise Initializer and set `config.unlock_strategy = :email`. You could also set it to `:both`. This will trigger the email that you are looking for.

### Solution 2

If, for whatever reason, you just want to tell the user that their account is locked without producing an unlock-token, you could add the following to your User model:

```
after_commit :send_account_locked_email, if: -> { locked_at_was_previously_changed? && locked_at.present? }

def send_account_locked_email
  # Call your mailer here.
end
```